# Cannot plot solution of an ODE using a large domain

Tags: octave, ode

I'm trying to solve a system of ODEs.  I'm using the `ode45d` command like so:

```
[t,x] = ode45d(@f, (t = linspace(0,100,1000)'),
               [sh0; ih0; rh0; sm0; lm0; im0; se0; ie0], [7], ones(8,1));
```

When I type the system of ODEs and this command in octave I get the right graph. The problem is that when I let the x-axis larger, the graph changes to something very strange.

When I let the domain of the ODEs bigger than 100, the only thing I get is a vertical line on the graph.

Is there someone who knows the function `ode45d` and its limitations, and who can tell me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my English.

Comment: This looks like a dynamic blow-up. Classical example *y'=y²*. This is not a problem of the solver. Try restricting the displayed range to approximately the first range to see if that is likely. Without knowing the differential equation, nothing much can be said. With knowing it, a detailed discussion belongs on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. I tried to use ode45d to solve easier systems of ODEs than that I want to solve, and I got the same problem when I engarge the domain, that's because I thought it was a limitation of the ode45d command, I thought the ode45d was unable to solve systems of ODEs in a very large domain. I'll post this question on math.stackexchange, then.